# How to remove options from select element without memory leak?

Tags: jquery, memory, memory-leaks, html-select

I'm trying to dynamically change options in my select. I noticed, this produce memory leak in IE8. Options does not removing from memory.

After that, I try my code in Chrome ver. 23, and I can see memory leak too.
I show there 2 version of code.

- jQuery verion [jsfiddle.net/84Axu/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/84Axu/1/)

  ```
      $('#btn').click(function () {
          $('#tstSelect').empty();
          for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
              var option = $('');
              option.text(i + 1);
              option.val(i + 1);
              $('#tstSelect').append(option);
          }
      });​
  ```
- Pure javascript version http://jsfiddle.net/3VFMt/.

  ```
      function btnClick() {
          // clear select
          var select = document.getElementById('tstSelect');
          while (select.firstChild)
              select.removeChild(select.firstChild);
          // fill select
          for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
              var option = document.createElement('option');
              option.text = i + 1;
              option.value = i + 1;
              document.getElementById('tstSelect').appendChild(option);
          }
      };
  ```

Both of this provides memory leaks on IE and Chrome.

Comment: As I see, latest firefox (17.0.1) does not provide memory leak in this cases.

Comment: If your application does a lot of insertion/removal of options, then you may like to explore reusing option elements in lieu of creating new. You can create one or more hidden `<select>` elements in which to park "removed" options. Reuse logic can be tricky but will reduce memory leaks and is very satisfying when you get it right.

Comment: I was thinking about something like that, but this issue is interesting.

Comment: I have one select and constant set of options for it. In my case, I need to show some subset of this options, and this subset may change in time. Another approach, that I can see, is to save all options in array, and remove/add they to select, when I need (dont create new options).

Comment: As I researched, chrome does not provide memory leak, its garbage collector rarely clean memory.
Fix for IE8: instead of using `$('#tstSelect').empty();` using `$('#tstSelect').html('');`

Comment: Thanks for that Zergatul - interesting.