# Updating list of <select> options using jquery and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to make an html select list of options update according to a selection made on a prior html select object. My jquery is below. This is being called correctly.

```
var brandName = $("#Brand").val();

$.get("updateTypes.php?q="+brandName, function(data) {

    $("#Type").remove();
    var typeData = JSON.parse(data);

    for (loop=0; loop < typeData.length; ++loop) {
        $("#Type").options.add(new Option(typeData[loop]));
    }
});
```

As I am using a singleton to interface with my mySQL database, this jquery function calls a 'go-between' .php file called updateTypes.php which is below:

```
include 'databaseInterface.php';
$brand = $_GET["q"];
$typesData = databaseInterface::getBrandTypes($brand);
return $typesData;
```

This calls the getBrandTypes function in my singleton below:

```
$query = "SELECT psTypeName FROM types WHERE brands_psBrandName='$BrandName'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die ("Couldn't execute query. ".mysqli_error($con));
$resultArray = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    extract($row);
    $resultArray[] = $psTypeName;   
}

return json_encode($resultArray);
```

The webpage correctly removes the existing options from the jquery function but fails to update them. It seems to go wrong when I decode the JSON data in the jquery. Why is it going wrong? Is the loop for updating the select object appropriate?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `$.getJSON` if your expecting a json response. You might also be able to use `$.each()` and then simply `.append()` to the `select` tag. You can reference `this.property` inside the `.each()`.

Something like the following:

```
$.getJSON("updateTypes.php?q="+brandName, function(data) {
    $("#Type").html('');
    $.each(data, function(){
        $("#Type").append('<option value="'+ this.value +'">'+ this.name +'</option>')
    )
})
```

This would assume your json response is something like the following:

`[ { name : "foo", value : "bar" }, { name : "another", value : "example" } ]`

Comment: This answer is great, but as stated by another answer, the statement `$("#Type").remove();` will remove the select object. The correct way to do it is using `$("#Type").html('');`. There is also missing punctuation in the code of the answer. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 13):

Your code `$("#Type").remove();` removes the select object not its options. The correct way of removing options is:

```
$("#Type option").remove();
```

or

```
$("#Type").html('');
```

The second solution seems to be better as stated here: [How to remove options from select element without memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052747/how-to-remove-options-from-select-element-without-memory-leak)

There is also an error in the part that adds new options. Your javascript code should be:

```
var brandName = $("#Brand").val();

$.get("updateTypes.php?q="+brandName, function(data) {

    $("#Type option").remove();
    var typeData = JSON.parse(data);

    for (loop=0; loop < typeData.length; loop++) {
        $("#Type").get(0).options.add(new Option(typeData[loop]));
    }
});
```

The `$('#Type').get(0)` method refers to the raw DOM object which has the "options" property that you wanted to use ([How to get a DOM Element from a JQuery Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677880/how-to-get-a-dom-element-from-a-jquery-selector))