# Populating html select box by data from mysql database depending on another select box

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I've been struggling with this problem for a while. I have read tons of posts and tutorials who do something simmilar but cant really get it working for me.
I need to make php form which contains 2 html select boxes : school and class.
I can easly get it to show all schools from my database but cant get my head around how to depending on selected school show classes from that school.

I know this question is more time consuming then others might be, but I will be very happy if you chose to help me!

Kristaps

Comment: Show your schools and classes database table. Atleast show column

Comment: You may want to find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: check this link: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384705/updating-list-of-select-options-using-jquery-and-ajax`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since, you have not provided database structure of your database. I
>   assumed from myself and wrote query accordingly.  Change your query as
>   per your need.

```
<div>
    <select class='Schools' name='SchoolName'>
        <option value="">Select School</option>
        <?
        $Query="SELECT SchoolIDColumnName,SchoolNameColumn FROM SchoolsTable";
        foreach($pdo->query($Query) as $row)
        {?>
        <option value="<?echo {$row['SchoolIDColumnName']};?>"><?echo {$row['SchoolNameColumn']};?></option>
        <?}?>
    </select>
</div>
<div class='ShowClassName'>
    <select>
        <option value="">Select Class Name</option>
    </select>
</div>

<script>
    $('.Schools').change(function(){
        var SchoolID=$('.Schools').val();
        $.ajax({url:"Ajax-ShowClassName.php?SchoolID="+SchoolID,cache:false,success:function(result){
            $('.ShowClassName').html(result);
        }});
    });
</script>
```

**Ajax-ShowClassName.php**

```
<?
$SchoolID=$_GET['SchoolID'];

$QueryClassName="SELECT * FROM ClassTable WHERE SchoolIDColumnName='$SchoolID'";
?>

<select name='ClassName'>
    <?  
    foreach($pdo->query($QueryClassName) as $row)
    {?>
    <option value="<?echo {$row['ClassIDColumnName']};?>"><?echo {$row['ClassColumnName']};?></option>
    <?}?>
</select>
```