# Make Select form are related each other in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

in there i have 3 `select input type` i want make it related each other.

here my view :

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">Location</label>
  <!-- <input id="geocomplete" type="text" name="location" placeholder="Type in an address" class="form-control" /> -->
  <select name='locations' class="form-control" id="map" required>
  <option value='' >- Location -</option>
    <?php 
      $zone = DB::table("zone")->get();
      foreach($zone as $zones) {
      echo "<option value='$zones->id'>$zones->zone</option>";
    }
    ?>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">Location</label>
  <!-- <input id="geocomplete" type="text" name="location" placeholder="Type in an address" class="form-control" /> -->
  <select name='location' class="form-control" id="map" required>
  <option value='' >- Location -</option>
    <?php 
      $zonets = DB::table("zonets")->get();
      foreach($zonets as $zonetss) {
        if($zonetss->id_zone == $zone->id){
          echo "<option value='$zonetss->id'>$zonetss->location</option>";
        }
      }
    ?>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">Location</label>
  <!-- <input id="geocomplete" type="text" name="location" placeholder="Type in an address" class="form-control" /> -->
  <select name='location_1' class="form-control" id="map" required>
  <option value='' >- Location -</option>
    <?php 
      $airport = DB::table("airport")->get();
      foreach($airport as $airports) {
      echo "<option value='$airports->id'>$airports->loc_airport</option>";
      }
    ?>
  </select>
</div>
```

this my table :

- table for zone :

  [image: first]
- table for zonets :

  [image: here]
- and this my table for airport :

  [image: here]

in there i want to make the select is related.

for example :

in select = `zone` i choose Jakarta (id = 3)

and then i want make `zonets` is only show data with `id_zone = 3`

and after that its same with the `zonets`, `airport` is only show data with the data with `id_zonets` same with `zonets` where i choose it.

I hope someone can help me, and make my script is work..

Comment: Firstly I recommend you checkout the docs for [Eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships) for the proper way to query related objects. Now everytime you select an option, you can do Ajax calls to fetch the children of a selected object, e.g. if you click on zone id=3, do an ajax call to fetch zonets with zone id=3 and populate the results to the zonets dropdown options.

Comment: You will need to use JS for this.

Comment: um, what JS i need u use ?

Comment: Few suggestions : 1) Do not make queries from view files directly. Do it in controller/route file at least. 2) set only 1st select elements options initially and use jquery ajax upon select change to fetch and set select options of 2nd and 3rd select elements. [ref](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17384808/3113599) 3) you cannot have same id attribute for multiple elements. You will use id to update select options. 4) Try to use @foreach and other blade directives. [ref](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#control-structures)